# Find last row value in 2nd column from the right

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet (well multiple spreadsheets) that have sales values for each month in each column - so these keep getting added to each month.

| Product | 03-2022 | 04-2022 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 33 | 46 | 79 |
| Product 2 | 20 | 32 | 52 |

I am looking for a way in Google Sheets to retrieve the last value in the 2nd from last column, so it would always be the most recent month and wouldn't need to be changed even as new columns are added before the Total column.

The spreadsheets I'm using have a lot more rows, and I can't reference a specific column as the most recent month is obviously constantly changing.

Any help would be really appreciated as I'm banging my head against a wall!!

Comment: Welcome. Please show us what your efforts are so far according to [ask].

Comment: last value in the 2nd [What?]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Paste this formula in a new tab assuming the source tab is named `Sheet1`

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:1000,,COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1)-1)
```

**In this case**
[image]

---

**More columns**
[image]